# Fetching data from Tempo API fails

Tags: apex, integration, callout, httprequest, proxy

I am trying to fetch data from Tempo API. I added and enabled Tempo URL in Remote Site settings. Now I am making a query to their API and it fails with error `Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"`. This is a cloud API and it has not a firewall. If I make the same request using curl or any other client it works fine. Also, in the sandbox, the code works.

Here is the code that I use:

```
String reqURL = 'https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs'; 

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setEndpoint(reqURL); 
req.setMethod('GET'); 
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); 
// I omitted an Authorization header, in this case, to not compromise sensitive data. The issue is not with authorisation. 
req.setTimeout(120000); 


Http http = new Http(); 
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req); 

system.debug(res.getBody());
```

I get this error:
`System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"`

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: If the same code its working in a sandbox, I'd say that it is a temporal issue, specially if you are using the cloud version. Play around with execute anonymous to make sure that prod and sandbox behave differently. On a side-note, maybe you'd like to try out "Named Credentials", so you neither have to authenticate by code nor have to maintain the Remote Site Settings ;)

Comment: I don't think this is a temporal issue. The issue lasts more than a week. If I execute the code anonymously, in the sandbox it's working as expected. On production the error that I described.

P.S.
Thank you for pointing to "Named Credentials". Didn't know about that feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround for this issue, I deployed a proxy server for proxying all requests to Tempo API.
Unfortunately, Salesforce Support also didn't give me a proper solution but told me that I need to upgrade my account to get priority support.